# How can I add link(url) to react native map callout?

Tags: react-native

I tried this :

```
<MapView.Marker id={marker.id}
                coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                title={marker.title}>
                <MapView.Callout style={styles.callout}  >
         <Text style={styles.link} onPress={this.openUrl.bind(this)}>
                   {this.props.marker.link} 
         </Text>
    </MapView.Callout>
 </MapView.Marker>
```

But openUrl function doesn't call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Text* doesn't contain onPress callBack, move *onPress* from *Text* to *MapView.Callout*.

```
<MapView.Callout
         onPress={this.openUrl.bind(this)}
         style={styles.callout}
       >
            <Text style={styles.link}>
              {this.props.marker.link}
            </Text>
</MapView.Callout>
```

**update:**
For having more than one link, you can use *Custom Callouts*. Remove onPress from callout and add clickable child to the callout:

```
      <MapView.Callout
        style={styles.callout}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={()=>{this.openUrl(this.props.marker.link1)}}
        >
          <Text style={styles.link}>
            {this.props.marker.link1}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={()=>{this.openUrl(this.props.marker.link2)}}
        >
          <Text style={styles.link}>
            {this.props.marker.link2}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </MapView.Callout>
```

Comment: But in that case I can't make more than one link in the callout

Comment: For adding more than one clickable link to the callout, you should use onPress in the callout children (see updated answer).